# rails confirm before delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my rails link_to

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(action: :delete,id: @user.id),data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

I tried the above method but it is directly deleting without any alert message. What wrong I made. Can any one correct it.

Comment: is jquery.js is included in your app?

Comment: @Debadatt Yes included

Answer (score 66):

Try this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(action: :delete,id: @user.id),method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the `data` hash is the only option in the provided solutions here that ended up working for me. Rails 4.1.2, Ruby 2.1.2p95, jquery-rails 3.1.1. That said, in other apps, I've used the `confirm` option outside the `data` hash, as an argument to link_to, and it has totally worked. What gives?

Comment: This stumped me for a while in Rails 4.1, without putting the confirm in the data hash the attribute is rendered as "confirm" instead of the proper "data-confirm"

Comment: Did they change this to data-confirm in Rails 4?

Answer (score 11):

Answer for rails 4.1.8  (question doesn't include version)

and standard resource    (also not specified)

1. `//= jquery_ujs`   must be included in application.js (possibly missing)
2. url is `user_path(@user)`
3. specify `:method => :delete`  (missing)
4. confirm message within `:data` (was good)
5. **destroy method** in controller (not delete)

> = link_to t(:delete) , user_path(@user), :method => :delete, :class => "btn btn-danger", :data => {:confirm => t(:are_you_sure )}

The url in the question seems to create a GET, rather than a DELETE method. This may work if :method was specified. imho it is unfortunate that there is no seperate named url helper for this.

Comment: //= jquery_ujs added after //= jquery and it works like charm now

Answer (score 10):

#### Before Rails 7

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', url_for(action: :delete, id: @user.id),
  method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

#### Rails 7 (with Turbo, out of the box)

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', url_for(action: :delete, id: @user.id),
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: this answer help me save a lot of time

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @installero didn't work for me in rails 7.0.3, I achieved a similar thing using `button_to`:

```rb
<%= button_to "Delete", @category, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } }, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: This is the one for the `button_to` helper, the asnwer was about `link_to` though

Answer (score 4):

```
link_to('Delete', {controller: :controller_name, id: id, action: :action_name}, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?", method: :delete)
```

Answer (score 3):

since Rails 7 Hotwire Turbo was introduced

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @post, class: 'btn btn-danger',data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>


<%= button_to "Destroy this post", @post, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger',  form: { data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should use :method option

   `<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(action: :delete,id: @user.id), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %>`
2. It's probably better to use button (and form) for this kind of action

Comment: Tried but no working when i inspect i can see `data-confirm="Are you sure?"` and `data-method="delete"`

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure, that syntax is right - check again please. It's supposed to be <%= link_to 'Text', '/some/path', method: :delete, confirm: 'Some text' %>.

Answer (score 1):

Rails confirmation popup box for destroy action:

```
    <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article),{:class=>'btn btn-success show_article' }%>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article),{:class=>'btn btn-warning edit'} %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', '#', "data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-target" => "#delete-#{article.id}",:class=>'btn btn-danger' %>
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-<%= article.id %>" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmation Box</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure to delete this article</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(action: :delete,id: @user.id), confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both the jQuery library and the jQuery driver for Rails included. The `jquery-rails` gem will take care of both of these in the later versions of Rails, from what I know.

Also, for better chances of compatibility with future versions of the jQuery driver, move the `:confirm` option outside `:data` and let the `jquery-rails` gem decide what to do with it.